# Why do I see the "'h' float to 'ht'" warning when I use \ead or \fntext for authors in cas-sc-template?

Tags: floats, footnotes, els-cas, email

No matter where I try to edit it, on overleaf or downloading it from the journal link and work on it on some editor on my computer, if I don't remove the `\ead{}` and `\fntext{}` for the authors when using the **cas-sc-template** of Elsevier. I get the following warning:

> `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.

Why is this? Previously I only have seen this warning for figures and tables. And more importantly, what is the solution? What should I do in order to get rid of this warning in a proper way?

Comment: This is normal behaviour. If you use `[h]` and the float cannot be placed `here` (about), then the list is empty and thus cannot be placed anywhere. So by default `[h]` is always interpreted as `[ht]`. In general never use just `[h]` use at least `[htp]` then it has more possibilities to place the float.

Comment: Because `h` is to limited. For example, where should be float, if there, where is inserted in text, no enough space for it? So with `ht` you tell LateX, that it is preferable to have float where is inserted, but if this is not possible let it be on the top of the next page.

Comment: @daleif and @Zarko I haven't used `[h]` in any place in my tex. If there is anything, it should be with the template which is not designed by me (`cas-sc.sty`).

Comment: Please, make a small compilable example that shows the warning

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you can find this template at overleaf as well https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-single-column-template/rsnbvrmnptyq

Comment: The template contains the line `\begin{table}[width=.9\linewidth,cols=4,pos=h]`.  Change `pos=h` to `pos=ht` and the warning will go away.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-single-column-template/rsnbvrmnptyq) at Overleaf contains the line (line 231, in the current version):

```latex
\begin{table}[width=.9\linewidth,cols=4,pos=h]
```

The `pos` option in the `els-cas` template is the same as LaTeX's standard optional argument to floating environments (like `table` and `figure`).  Change `pos=h` to `pos=ht` and the warning will vanish:

```latex
\begin{table}[width=.9\linewidth,cols=4,pos=ht]
```